# css relative heigt for div till page end

Tags: css, height

I have a div that has a relative position to the top of the page with a lot of divs and elements inbetween. the heigth of the div must be till te end of the page, but no further.
[image]

i know you can use something like 100vh te get the exact lengt of the page, but the distance to the top of the page needs to be subtracted.

is there a css only fix for this problem?

Comment: This can easily be done with flexbox. You'll just have to allow the last box to grow accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out doing it with position absolute with bottom 0, this will align the div at the bottom of the page always. Alternatively, if it's a footer that loads after all the content of your page and your web page content is more than 100 vh height, then you can try position sticky with bottom 0 as well.